# ERROR java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, gradle, liferay, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying just do this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com.br");
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver
```

I'm using Liferay DXP with Gradle.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: in your IDE can you open that class?
Most likely it is due to Version Mismatch (you are using a version which does not have that class).  Figure out all the dependencies and where that class exists.  

or there was an error in the constructor of that class (less likely)

Comment: Try HttpClient to be over 4.5.

Comment: which classe @BojanPetkovic ?

Comment: HttpClientBuilder.  You are likely linking to two versions of HttpClient library in your code.  
figure out which httpClient library versions you have.  If it is below 4.5 try and upgrade it.

Comment: I'm using like this:

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'

but I don't know if other library is importing other version..

Comment: you need to check dependency tree and figure out which version is exactly being pulled in.

Comment: did you solve this issue ? I'm using htmlunit 2.70.0 and still facing this problem